# Objeto no es null pero se interpreta como null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, cshtml

Tengo un objeto con el siguiente modelo:

```
public class DatosModelo
{
    public string IdModelo { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

El cual es enviado a la vista en una lista de ellos, para capturar el Title y pintar el valor tengo la siguiente función:

```
@foreach (var dato in Model.Datos)
{
    if (dato.Title.Equals("tituloM2"))
    {
        @dato.Value
    }
}
```

Recorro el modelo de datos y busco si el title es igual que `"tituloM2"` pero me salta:

> **Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'No se puede realizar enlace en tiempo de ejecución en una referencia NULL.'**

Dejo una captura para demostrar que si existe y se llama igual:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He mirado la solución [aqui](https://www.dokry.com/3679) pero no llego a comprender por qué si recorre antes varios bucles iguales sin ningún problema y decide por magia negra que en este debe saltar excepción.

**¿Por qué salta justo en mitad de la ejecución y no al principio siendo todos igual?**

Comment: Comprueba si estás compilando en modo *release* o *debug*. En algunos modos de compilación se aplican optimizaciones que *falsean* la información que se muestra al depurar.

Comment: Veo que en ningun caso estas usando objetos de tipo dynamic. Llegaste a comprobar si la InnerException te daba mas información?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No era magia negra

Mirando bien el recorrido de el bucle me encontré con un elemento con `Title=null`, entonces al recorrer el `foreach` y encontrar ese elemento `null` saltaba la excepción.

Si añado una comparación al if como:

```
if (dato.Title != null && dato.Title.Equals("tituloM2"))
{
    @dato.Value
}
```

Evito la excepción.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que parece es que está sin inicializar, que tal algo así:

```
public class DatosModelo
{
    public string IdModelo { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public DatosModelo()
    {
        IdModelo = "";
        Title = "";
        Value = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ese no parece ser el problema, en la captura que anexa del proceso de depuración se ve que el campo `Title` tiene valor, por lo tanto: ha sido inicializado.

Comment: Cierto, no me he fijado bien, disculpa. He visto que el Id era null y pense que seria por eso , pero Title tiene valor. Que estas usando Dato.Title.EstoNoSeVe